# Error: expression must have class type?

Tags: class, types, c++-cli

probably such a simple fix, but I cannot seem to figure out what the issue is.
the 2nd line is what is having the issue, what did I do wrong?

```
System::String^ userinfo = DownloadHTMLPage("http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/auser3.php");
String^ str2 = gcnew String(userinfo.c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

`userInfo` is a pointer, so you should write that line as

```
System::String^ str2 = gcnew System::String(userinfo->c_str());
```

Comment: Error: class system string has no member c_str

Comment: i got the function from somewhere i don't know, and the other bits that you see now are what i did.

Comment: There is a `c_str` method, but in `std::string`. Are you sure that `DownloadHTMLPage` returns a `System::String`?

Comment: im 100% sure on that.

Comment: So simply remove the method call and you'll have the `String` you need: `str2 = gcnew System::String(userinfo);`

Comment: String^ str2 = gcnew System::String(userinfo); this line works, however when i use str2 it gives me the same error lol im back where i started.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you use str2?

Comment: String^ find1 = "&UserId=";
String^ find2 = "&k1="; String^ find3 = "&k2=";
size_t found = str2.find(find1);

Comment: `find` is a standard c++ method. You should use `IndexOf()` for a `System::String` object. `Int32 found = str2->IndexOf(find1);`

Answer (score 0):

`System::String` and `String` are the same class. Since .Net strings are immutable, you don't need to make another one using `gcnew`, you can just use `userinfo` directly.

```
String^ userinfo = DownloadHTMLPage("http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/auser3.php");

// Use userinfo in your code, or...
String^ str2 = userinfo;
```

Based on the comments on the other answer, it looks like you're getting C++ strings and .Net strings confused. *They are not the same class!*

- Reference for C++ strings:
  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/
- Reference for .Net strings:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

To convert from one to the other, use `marshal_as`, like this:

```
#include <marshal_cppstd.h>

String^ managed = "foo";

std::string unmanagedNarrow = marshal_as<std::string>(managed);
std::wstring unmanagedWide = marshal_as<std::wstring>(managed);

String^ managed2 = marshal_as<String^>(unmanagedNarrow);
String^ managed3 = marshal_as<String^>(unmanagedWide);
```